# JasperReport .jasper-file from database

Tags: java, spring-boot, controller, jasper-reports

I'm working with jasperreports in my Springboot project. I can generate a PDF based on data and a .jasper-file in my resources folder. However, I want no .jasper-file in my resourcesfolder, I want to save the .jasper-file as a bytearray in my database.

I can't figure out how to create a jasperReport object from the attachment, please advice.

Here is my controller for returning the created report.

```
@GetMapping("api/V1/pdfDocument/{finDocId}")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> generatePdf(@PathVariable long finDocId) throws Exception {

    FinancialDocument financialDocument = financialDocumentService.getDocumentById(finDocId);

    ArrayList<FinancialDocument> documentCollection = new ArrayList<>();
    documentCollection.add(financialDocument);
    JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanCollectionDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(documentCollection);

    Attachment reportAttachment = attachmentService.getAttachmentById(1L);

    JasperReport jasperReport = new InputStream(....);

    JasperPrint report = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, beanCollectionDataSource);

    byte[] data = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(report);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "inline;filename=invoice.pdf");

    return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF).body(data);
    //return null;
}
```

Here is my attachment class

```
public class Attachment {

private Long attachmentId;
private String attachmentName;
private String attachmentType;
private byte[] attachmentFile;
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take the byte array that contains the Jasper report design and wrap it into a [`ByteArrayInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html):

```
Attachment reportAttachment = attachmentService.getAttachmentById(1L);
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(reportAttachment.attachmentFile);
JasperPrint report = JasperFillManager.fillReport(inputStream, null, beanCollectionDataSource);
```